# CoCreateInstanceEx returns 0x80070005

Tags: c++, windows-7, dcom

I have a DCOM object and I'm trying to start it remotely. But the function CoCreateInstance is returning the value 0x80070005 - Access Denied. My test is being done with Windows 7. What could be wrong?

```
   HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
   hr = CoInitializeSecurity(0, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);

    COAUTHINFO ca = {RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, 0, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,0, EOAC_NONE };

    COAUTHIDENTITY id = {0};
    ca.pAuthIdentityData = &id;
    id.User = (USHORT*) L"user";
    id.UserLength = userLenght;
    id.Password = (USHORT*) L"password";
    id.PasswordLength = passwordLenght;
    id.Domain = (USHORT*)L"domainName";
    id.DomainLength = domainName;
    id.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_ANSI;

    COSERVERINFO c = {0};
    c.pwszName = L"machineName";
    c.pAuthInfo = &ca;
    MULTI_QI res = {0};
    res.pItf = NULL;
    res.hr = S_OK;
    res.pIID = &IID_ITextAnimationProxy;
    hr = CoCreateInstanceEx(CLSID_TextAnimationProxy,0, CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER,&c,1,&res);
```

Comment: Have you tried running `DCOMCNFG` and fixing your security problems? Do you expect someone to guess if you have ActiveDirectory/Domain and what your user accounts and groups are, and what those user accounts and groups permissions are with respect to the DCOM server you're trying to instantiate?

Comment: This question itself helped me a lot. The only change required was `SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE`. I also didn't call `CoInitializeSecurity`